# azure-kusto-python: preserve data types in dynamic values

Tags: python, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using Kusto SDK for Python to query data from Azure Data Explorer. When some query returns single values having Kusto `datetime` type, they are conveniently converted to Python own `datetime` type.

```py
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder

cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net"
# use another auth method if necessary
kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_az_cli_authentication(cluster)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)
db_name = "Samples"

query_1 = "print x=datetime(2022-09-22)"
response_1 = client.execute_query(db_name, query_1)
result_1 = response_1.primary_results[0].to_dict()["data"]
print(result_1)
print(type(result_1[0]["x"]))
```

Result:

```
[{'x': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())}]
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

However, using the [`make_list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction) function to aggregate values from multiple rows, datetimes are implicitly converted to strings. From what I understand, this is due to `make_list` returning a [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic) value, which gets serialized as JSON and thus causes non-JSON values to be converted to strings. This is a minimum example:

```py
query_2 = "print x=dynamic(datetime(2022-09-22))"
response_2 = client.execute_query(db_name, query_2)
result_2 = response_2.primary_results[0].to_dict()["data"]
print(result_2)
print(type(result_2[0]["x"]))
```

Result:

```
[{'x': '2022-09-22T00:00:00.0000000Z'}]
<class 'str'>
```

Is there any setting or workaround to prevent datetimes inside dynamic values to be converted to strings?

Comment: You can give a full working example by using the publicly available cluster *help* and one of its databases, e.g., *Samples* https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples

Comment: You are "blaming" *make_list* but gives an example that doesn't use it. Dynamic arrays are not strongly typed. You can mix types or create arrays of homogenous types, anyways it is your responsibility to indicate the data types when you read the values.